# Java handle dates into database

Tags: java, date, jdbc, insert

I have a date that I would like to insert into my database in dd/mm/yyyy              format(25/12/2014)

My code accepts a Booking object with a date as one of its fields.
My code throws an error at the "Date currentDate = sd.parse(book.GetActualCheckInDate()); statement that says:

no suitable mothod found for parse(java.util.Date)
method java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(java.lang.String, java.text.ParsePosition) is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.text.DateFormat.parse(java.lang.String) is not applicable(actual argument java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion)

```
public int InsertBooking(Booking book) throws SQLException
    {
    int retCode = 2;
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Date currentDate = sd.parse(book.GetActualCheckInDate());
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime());

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HotelDatabase");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String insertStatements = ("INSERT INTO BOOKING " +
                "(BOOKINGID, ACTUALCHECKINDATE)" +
                "VALUES " + "(" + book.GetBookingID() + "," + "'" + sqlDate + "'" + ")"); 
     }
```

Comment: Why do you want to parse it to `Date`, if it is already a `Date`?

Comment: Did you hear about [PreparedStatement](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem that i see is the pattern in the SimpleDateFormat. In `dd/mm/yyyy`
**mm** represent minutes. Use instead `dd/MM/yyyy`.

The second thing, is that are you trying to pass an string to a Date field on the DB. Let JDBC do the job to parse into the correct format for your database using [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1):

What does book.GetActualCheckInDate() return?
It must be a valid date formatted string. Because parse method is to convert the date in string format to date in Date Formate.

Rather if you want a Date to be converted into a date string in a specified formate then you must use format method of SimpleDateFormat. Check out the below solutions

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String someDate = "22/03/1991";
            SimpleDateFormat strToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date currentDate = strToDate.parse(someDate);
            System.out.println("Date is :  " + currentDate);

            String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
            SimpleDateFormat dateToStr = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            String formattedDate = dateToStr.format(currentDate);
            System.out.println("Formated Date is : " + formattedDate);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception is : " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```